# Simulate onClick listener using onTouch

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I created a kind of mask over my UI that registers and intercepts touches. 
My problem is that I need to know when user clicks the UI view and perform an action with that knowledge.

For example I want to know that user clicked the `Button`. I create a invisible layer over it with onTouch listener.

```
layer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        registerTouch();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Thanks to that, I know that user clicked over the button, the button is still clickable, because I didn't consume this event.

The problem is - when user touches that UI element, and MOVES the finger, the button is not pressed, yet I still register it being pressed. 
I can't use `onClickListener` because it doesn't pass touches through my invisible layer.

How should I "simulate" onClick using onTouches?

(The below example is simplified logic of my whole module, someone could suggest to move all that into the button's onClickListener, however the whole idea of my project is to crate kind of universal logic for different elements across the application)

Comment: How about using the other MotionEvent actions, such as  ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS?  Otherwise, if for some reason you are limited to just ACTION_DOWN, you'll need to add the same logic to your code that Android uses to determine "click" events.  (Since, as you already see, a simple touch is not equivalent to a click.)

Answer (score 0):

I think [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) will do what you want.  You create an instance of GetureDetector with [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) callbacks passed into its constructor.  These callbacks will fire as it interprets the MotionEvents that flow through it.

You can also consider using [GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) to replace your transparent overlay, since it sounds like it does almost exactly the same thing.